# Supervisors behaviour

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

when implementing a supervisor.. If, in the supervisor module, I do something like

> init([_]) ->
>   {ok,
>   {{one_for_one, 5, 60},
>   [{reverese, {reverse, start_reverse, []}, permanent, brutal_kill, worker,[]}]}}.

and the reverse function is:

> start_reverse() ->
>     Pid=spawn(?MODULE,reverse,[]).

It will not work since the start_reverse function exits normally in every case. However, when I add a line like this:

> start_reverse() ->
>     Pid=spawn(?MODULE,reverse,[]),
>     {ok,Pid}.

It works, even when the function exits normally as well. Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually.. It isnt really required for the supervisor child process to be a `gen_server`. The supervisor [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html) specifically mentions that

> The start function must create and link to the child process, and should return {ok,Child} or {ok,Child,Info} where Child is the pid of the child process and Info an arbitrary term which is ignored by the supervisor.

which is the reason why when you returned `{ok, Pid}` it worked..

Answer (score 5):

Easily,

The problem is that the `supervisor` needs a specific calling convention to support the shutdown and initialization of processes. Your code with a low-level `spawn` ignores that convention. You should either

- Use a gen_something behaviour, `gen_server` is most common.
- Spawn the process using `proc_lib`
- Use a `supervisor_bridge`

Otherwise, your code will not take advantage of OTP at all. And you want it to.

Comment: Can you tell me why I need or should want OTP?

Comment: @dkk: That would be a good topic for another question? Search for it, it has probably been answered already...

Comment: FYI I have created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880499/why-use-otp-with-erlang